# Fail to build mysql connector/c (libmysql) from source in cygwin

Tags: mysql, build, cygwin, cmake, libmysql

I am trying to build MySQL's "Connector/C" from source in cygwin and there are problems.

**-some context-**

We could talk a lot about *why* anyone would want use `libmysql` in cygwin. In this case, it is just simpler to do some unix development on a windows box with the cygwin tool set.

From my research, it looks like I could get an older version (5.1, maybe) of the connector to build OK. But cygwin support trailed off when the MySQL developers switched from `./configure` to `cmake` driven build configuration.

The version of the source tar-ball that MySQL offers up for download is 6.0.2 so that is the one I'm working on.

**-one (sort-of) solved problem-**

The first problem I encountered was an incompatible redeclaration of `dtoa()` found in `stdlib.h`. (Many others who have tried to build various recent versions encountered this problem, also - if google is any guide.) There are various suggestions lurking on the net to resolve this. My choice: temporarily replacing `stdlib.h` with one that has the `dtoa()` definition removed. *Ugly*, true. But it *works*.

(This 'fix' eliminates an early compile error and the process runs clear through to linking, where it fails for apparently unrelated reasons.)

**-an unsolved problem-**

The `libmysql` code relies on `yaSSL`. This seems to be the case even though I gave `cmake` the `-DWITH_OPENSSL=1` parameter, which is accepted only *after* I added the `openssl-devel` package to my environment with the cygwin setup-tool/package-manager. `yaSSL` seems to be using 'pure virtual' class members. From my (somewhat limited) knowledge of the internals of C++, this means that the compiler implicitly assumes the declaration of the special symbol/function `__cxa_pure_virtual()` and this causes the linker to search for a (single) definition of the `__cxa_pure_virtual()` function.

The way the code and build process are structured, each of the `yaSSL` source implementation files is compiled into an object file. Many of those files reference another that defines (i.e. contains an implementation of) `__cxa_pure_virtual()`. In the linking stage, each object that contains a definition conflicts with each other. (Because the symbol is defined as `extern`, or more specifically:

```
extern "C" {
  int __cxa_pure_virtual() {
    assert("Pure virtual method called." == "Aborted");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

These definitions are in a shared namespace. Thus, the linker has not been given a rule by which to decide which one to link-to from each reference.) The result is a `multiple definition error`, e.g.:

```
CMakeFiles/libmysql.dir/__/extlib/yassl/taocrypt/src/algebra.cpp.o:algebra.cpp:(.text+0x40): multiple definition of `___cxa_pure_virtual'
CMakeFiles/libmysql.dir/__/extlib/yassl/taocrypt/src/aes.cpp.o:aes.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

I've tried some highly simplistic attempts to resolve this problem.

- I removed all definitions of `__cxa_pure_virtual()` but that just replaces the multiple-definition errors with undefined-reference errors.
- I changed all definitions of `__cxa_pure_virtual()` to `inline` in the vain hope that the compiler would remove the external reference from a function that was used inline. (I'm not sure when C++ uses a lookup-table as a layer of indirection but it seems that `inline` may not be an option in those cases.) If I remember the specific result of that test: it created the same result as *no* definition of `__cxa_pure_virtual()`.
- I started looking for uses of pure-virtual functions in the `libmysql` source but that seemed like a rabbit hole...
- I *considered* studying the build process in order to place a definition of `__cxa_pure_virtual()` in an independent object file (and, then, I would remove the definition from every other object file).

I'm looking for options between (and including)

1. the minimum modification to the project to make it build something useful, and
2. the correct patch-set that makes the build process work correctly on all currently supported platforms *and* cygwin.

"Between" because there might be some intermediate alternatives that should be considered. So, the way I see it, the most important question here is, *"What is the simplest/easiest fix for the multiple-definition error (in this context)?"* maybe followed closely by, *"What kinds of things should be fed back to the MySQL team so that the build process can be (re-)ported to cygwin?"*

**-final notes-**

If MySQL's developers have abandoned cygwin support, I don't know what would bring their attention back to that platform.

I would like to see that developers who have cause to work in cygwin could retain the option to test their code against a cygwin/unix build of the MySQL connector.

There might be some value in the community maintaining a knowledge base containing, at least, the bare minimum set of hacks to make the latest version (and, maybe, some recent versions) of the connector build usefully in cygwin. A good first step toward that might be some discussion here on stackoverflow, maybe even as comments and answers on this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need Connector/C built with Cygwin? Would not normal win32 libmysql.dll  suffice?

Some ideas to get it compiling:

a)you're trying to compile Connector/C with gcc as C++ compiler, better don't. Use g++.

b)cmake . -DSKIP_SSL=1 (looking into CMakeLists.txt suggests it will remove yassl)

And yes, MySQL has abandoned cygwin (and it did not support it for many years now). I do not know what might get Oracle to reenable it back, they are currently rather into cutting platform support (e.g HPUX and AIX are abandoned). Also personally,I  would not see much value in Cygwin port, it is not the hottest platform, as long as you can use native Windows port.

Comment: It was (b): `cmake` *did* respond to `-DSKIP_SSL=1` and this has eliminated the linker problems on `yaSSL`'s object files. It looks like the build process is now running to completion. Thanks for the insight!

Note that I was OK on (a): my environment was choosing a good C++ compiler by default.

Comment: I got around to testing it: I can verify that C code linked to the resulting `libmysql` build is successfully connecting to (and retrieving data from) a MySQL server, version 5.5.8, configured as it comes packaged with WAMPSERVER 2.1. Thanks again, Vladislav! Again a note: my first tests failed because several of the 'informational' `mysql_get_...()` functions wouldn't link. (`nm` says they are defined in the `libmysqlclient.a` file but `ld` can't find them.) However, I could see that some functions *did* work. I ended up getting data from a `MYSQL_ROW` fetched from a `MYSQL_RES`ult just fine.

Comment: Just to share my positive experience (upvoted the answer too). What did make mysqlconnector-c-6.0.2 to compile inside Cygwin for me, was this: `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DSKIP_SSL=1` and then `make` finished successfully. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Why do you need Connector/C built with Cygwin?"  Getting things like Perl DBD::mysql to build under Cygwin seem to require MySQL client libraries compiled for Cygwin.  I suspect this is at least partially because mysql_config spits out Windows-style compiler options; there may be other reasons.

Comment: How did you get past the error: conflicting types for 'dtoa'?  I am getting this error trying to compile 5.5.8 or 5.5.20. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62627

Comment: rename dtoa to something else, e.g my_dtoa or whatever. This is what patch in the bug also does.