# MySQL include files from Cygwin gcc

Tags: mysql, cygwin

How can I set up MySQL so that i can have header-files and libraries in my Cygwin gcc C++ builds?

I have seen descriptions on the web, but it seems to refer to stuff I don't have, Like "*configure*.
(I suspect MySQL has changed their build system).

Using an older version could be an option, but I would prefer to have the same versions as on Linux.

I have a full Cygwin install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what's wrong with just using the Windows version? It works fine.

Then, I've wanted to do the same thing as you, and it can be done. Note that I haven't attempted to build the server; all I was interested in was the MySQL client library so I could do some simple client development in the Cygwin environment.

So what do you have to do in order to build the client library on Cygwin?

First, get the tarball. I used `mysql-5.5.13.tar.gz`. Unpack it in a suitable location, like `/usr/local/src`.

Then, install the `CMake` build system via the Cygwin installer. MySQL has switched from GNU Autotools to CMake. CMake is a meta-build system. It generates Makefiles and other build scripts for specific build environments.

Of course, you also need `make` and `gcc`.

I had to apply an [innocuous little patch posted on the MySQL forum by one Hiroaki Kawai](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?117,407537,418282#msg-418282) in order to get the stuff to compile:

> Finally, I renamed all dtoa() to _dtoa() in mysql/strings/dtoa.c.
>   The function is static, and should be safe to be renamed.

You can patch using Perl:

```
perl -pi.orig -e 's/\bdtoa\b/_dtoa/g' strings/dtoa.c
```

Then, in the top source directory, type:

```
cmake .
make mysqlclient
```

You'll get two static libraries in `libmysql/`, `libclientlib.a` and `libmysqlclient.a`. I don't know that the former is (possibly just a build artefact), but the latter is the real thing.

```
cp /usr/local/src/mysql-5.5/libmysql/libmysqlclient.a /usr/local/lib/
```

But it's static, and you likely want a dynamic library. This is where the [Cygwin docs](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html) come in handy. So:

```
module=mysqlclient
gcc -shared -o cyg${module}.dll \
-Wl,--out-implib=lib${module}.dll.a \
-Wl,--export-all-symbols \
-Wl,--enable-auto-import \
-Wl,--whole-archive lib${module}.a \
-Wl,--no-whole-archive -lz
```

That'll create the shared library `cygmysqlclient.dll` and the import library `libmysqlclient.dll.a`. Copy both to `/usr/local/bin`. And that's it.

Here's [another question on building the MySQL client library on Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6258898/269126).

Comment: Looks great - but in my setup cmake is crashing :-(

Comment: Crashing? What are the symptoms?